# How to calculate total price and deprice on EJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ejs

I'm trying to calculate total price when user click on the image and reduce price when user delete the image out by using EJS that call data base of items on MySQL which it have price.

This is my html page with ejs and js

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){ //when click on the image of item it, item will show out on canvas.
            $('.items_img').click(function(){
                var path = $(this).attr('data-title');
                alert(path);
                addImage(path, 500, 500, 0.5, -90, 3);
            })
       });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
                                    <% for(var i=0; i<categories.length; i++){ %>
                                        <div class="tab-pane <% if(i==0){ %> active <% } %>" id="<%= categories[i].id %>a">
                                            <% for(var j=0; j<items.length; j++){ %>
                                                    <% if(items[j].category_id == categories[i].id){ %>
                                                <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
                                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                                        <img class="group list-group-image items_img" src="/pic_items/<%= items[j].picture_path %>" data-title='/anime_items/<%= items[j].anime_path %>' data-target='<%= items[j].price %>' alt="Test" />
                                                        <div class="caption">
                                                            <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                                                            <%= items[j].title %>   
                                                            </h4>
                                                            <p class="group inner list-group-item-text"> <%= items[j].description %> </p>
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                                    <p class="">Width <%= items[j].width %> CM</p>
                                                                    <p class="">Height <%= items[j].height %> CM</p>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <% } %>
                                            <% } %>
                                        </div>
</body>
</html>
```